# NoSQL Database Design for FSA

Tags: database, database-design, nosql, nosql-aggregation

I need to design a NoSQL database for a system that is using an FSA(Fare Service Aggregator) which is having a very heavy load including major scenarios, database aggregates, and queries.

Are any references on how to design a NoSQL database of about 10-15 pages? 
Video tutorials or examples would do. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no database design in NoSQL, it's literally a document dump. The major problem with NoSQL is how to query all the garbage in it. Mostly they all are Key-Value stores, totally unsuitable for business requirements. If document is too big maybe split it. I would suggest Couchbase to play with, because it's almost got SQL for querying objects (must have called it BackSQL) which it seems done right, so there is a chance you will be able to implement something using it. Will be 30x slower than RDBMS, but it's a trade off for NoSQL "scalability" (when you can horizontally add a dozen of servers to compensate slow index building and scan).

https://docs.couchbase.com/tutorials/todo-app/design/data-modeling.html
https://resources.couchbase.com/c/relational-no-sql-wp